# Do i3 workspaces have to be linear?

Tags: desktop-environment, i3, workspaces, enlightenment

Currently the way i3 does workspaces, they're all linear 0-9. Under a normal workflow this typically means you have one workspace for browsing the web, and one for managing media, and messaging/chat .. etc.

Browsing for alternative ideas, I found this description for Enlightenment,

> Enlightenment allows the user to have a grid of workspaces called virtual desktops. Switching between them is achieved by hurling the mouse cursor to the edge of the screen, at which the desktop appears to slide across to reveal the next. The maximum grid size is eight by eight desktops, and the user can have 32 grids (each with a different background), making 2048 total possible desktop spaces (users can enable a map of the desktops, in case they get lost, which is called the pager).
>   The desktop dragbar allows a desktop to be 'slid back' to reveal the desktop 'underneath'. **The E team use the analogy of sheets of paper, stacked on top of each other, where the user can slide off a piece partially to reveal what's beneath.**

I kind of like that philosophy. Normally for my projects, I need

- An editor for the front-end code (under a different repo)
- An editor for the back-end code (under a different repo)
- A database connection
- A browser, to view and research the project's problems.

In this sense, the linear organization of i3 doesn't make sense and this is really what I *want*. Is there anyway to get this out of i3?

I would rather think of Workspace 1 as "Project 1" and then go

- up to the browser
- left to the back-end of the project
- right to the front-end of the project
- down to my sql-client.

Some of them get a bit more complex. For example, I could see have left-left going to testing the back-end, and right-right go to the testing of the front end.

Is there any way to hack together a notion of a "project" which has different facets *unique* to it that I can access relative to the "project"?